# PropertyChangeCallBack not firing on DependencyProperty in a UserControl

Tags: wpf, xaml, dependency-properties

Stumped : I am in the initial stages of creating a month planner control that need to carry out some UI action I The control when supplying a date from the ViewModel bound in XAML. When I run the code, the ViewModel does return the value but the PropertyChangeCallBack is not firing. I have done exactly the same thing in an `public class ExtendedDataGrid : DataGrid` control and that work fine but it is almost like you have to do something different with UserControls. Here is the basis of my code:

```cs
public partial class DiaryMonthViewUserControl : UserControl
{
    private DateTime _topDate;


    public DiaryMonthViewUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // Property to get the date from the ViewModel for processing. This will fire and event to set the month we want to display
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TheDateProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("TheDate", typeof(DateTime),
                      typeof(DiaryMonthViewUserControl),
                      new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(DateTime.Today, OnDatePropertyChanged, null));

    public void SetTheCurrentDate(DateTime CurrentDate)
    {
        _topDate = CurrentDate;

        // Like Outlook, whatever date we supply, I want the first top level displayed date for the month
        if (_topDate.Day > 1)
            _topDate = _topDate.AddDays(-(_topDate.Day-1)); // First day of the month

        // Get to the first Monday before the 1st of the month if not on a Monday
        while (_topDate.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Monday)
            _topDate = _topDate.AddDays(-1);

        // I will set the UI here once I have solved this problem.
        MakeChangesToTheUIPlease();
    }

    private static void OnDatePropertyChanged(DependencyObject Source, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var control = Source as DiaryMonthViewUserControl;

        if (control != null)
            control.SetTheCurrentDate((DateTime)e.NewValue);
    }

    [Bindable(true)]
    public DateTime TheDate
    {
        get { return (DateTime)GetValue(TheDateProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TheDateProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

I have also tried using `new PropertyChangedCallback(OnDatePropertyChanged)` as a parameter and that still does not work.

My binding is as follows:

```
<my:DiaryMonthViewUserControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" x:Name="diaryMonthViewUserControl1" 
                              VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="325" Width="476" TheDate="{Binding Path=CurrentDate}" />
```

When I run the code my ViewModel breaks on the getter for CurrentDate and if I remove the CurrentDate binding then it does not. The problem is that the call back is not firing and, for the life of me, I cannot fathom why.

Any help would be much appreciated, particularly links to articles that may cover this problem.

Comment: You mention you can break on the getter, but isn't the callback going to be fired by code that would hit the setter?

Comment: OK, I have just discovered something that is not the answer but moving closer. If I use exactly the same code but change the type to int then is works but a type of DateTime does not. Is there a known problem with DateTime types as Dependency properties?

Comment: New to Wpf but an old hand at WiForms programming, I feel that I can guess how this works. The Binding in my XAML to the Depemdency property calls the getter on the bound property on the view model and then set the values in the GetValue() and SetValue() for the dependency property and then it will fire the changed callback event. The Binding does extract the value from the view model but does nothing else at all. I thought that I must have simple missed something or mande someting private that should have been public, as I have created a couple of dependency properties before

Comment: However, what is really strange is that when I change the property type from DateTime to either string or int and then change all of the other corresponding properties and calls to match that type, it works. It’s like DateTime does not work on Dependency Properties but I know that they do. Is there something that I need to consider when creating a Dependency Property on a User control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PropertyChanged callback only fires if the *immediate property* is changed, that means the whole DateTime object would need to be replaced, if properties of the DateTime object are changed the event will not be raised. This is why it works for primitive types like int.

If you want to execute some method whenever any property of the DateTime changed you could implement a DateTime class which provides notifications. You can then execute the method whenever any of the properties change.

Comment: Fantastic - Thanks a lot and after about 2 minutes thougt I realised that I would, therefore, need to return **new** DateTime(dateObj.Year, dateObj.Month, dateObj.Day) from my View Model rahter than simply return dateObj; As you said, this creates a brand new object for the dateTime because it is not a primitive type which then forces the on change callback event to fire.

Comment: Ah - now I tried returning new DateTime and thought it worked but then realised that I had converted the value type to a primitive type, int, which worked anyway. Converting it back to dateTime and then trying it with **new** still does not work. Looking for more ideas or more clarity on what you suggest.

Comment: I'd suggest you create a class which is basically a bindable DateTime, which gives you change notifications when one of the properties change, then you can subscribe to all of those and call your update method. I do not know what all your classes look like, there possibly is an easier way to do this.

Comment: OK, I will try this but being fairly new to Wpf I am going to have to work this out. I am quite surprised that this is not ttally straight forward as I can see that this should be required frequently.

Comment: OK, I have a solution but will give credit to the last answer because it got me thinking and have a solution that works for now. 
`class DateTimeObject
    {
        public DateTime TheDateTime { get; set; }
    }
`
Then simply create an instance and bind that to the XAML using a DependencyProperty of type DateTimeObject. Once in my UserControl I simply extract the DateTime property. Not nice but it works until I find a better solution.